# Ubuntu iso won't burn to blank DVD

Tags: dvd, burning

I am trying to use Ubuntu in virtualbox. I have downloaded it but it doesn't burn to a blank DVD. Currently using windows xp. Any Help?

Comment: Take a look at [How to burn Ubuntu to a DVD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto)

Answer (score 2):

If you are only installing in virtualbox, there's no need to waste a DVD.  You can just provide the ISO file directly to virtualbox.

Just create the virtual machine as you normally would, click the settings button, and then go to the "Storage" section.  Click the "Empty" CD icon, click the other CD icon next to "CD/DVD drive", and finally click "Choose a virtual disk file." and select your iso.  (see screenshot).  Then boot the machine and it will automatically boot the iso.
[image]